# How can I check if a user is logged in on another computer?

Tags: php

I have MYSQL table with users in it. The user can log in using PHP code. Their name is stored in SESSION variable. How can I check if the user is logged in already on another computer to forbid them logging in again?

**Scenario:**

Computer 1:
USER1 is logged in

Computer 2:
USER1 tries to log in again but they can't because they're already logged in on another computer.

Comment: You're not using the database in any capacity to manage authenticated users currently browsing the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a column "isLogged" in the databank and set it to true o false when the user starts or end a session.
I was doing that and works fine.

Comment: But the user has to end the session manually and what if he doesn't?

Comment: in Mysql,
SET SESSION wait_timeout = 60;

Answer (score 0):

To make sure he doesn't log in again on another computer you could update a field against the database to mark him as being logged in and then check this field when the user tries to log in.

```
<?php

if ($_SESSION["MySession"] != "") {
  //Update database field to set this user as actively browsing. 
  //Also set a timestamp so you know when he last visited a page.
}

?>
```

However, the user would have to physically log out on the other computer to log in again on a new one. You could implement a timer to clear the field in the database as well so it allows him to log in after a certain amount of time of inactivity.

You could create a cron and run it every 5 mins OR you could just run some code at the top of your page again that sets all `user_logged_in` fields to false where they haven't been active for the past `x` minutes.

So in order:

1. User logs into the website, `$_SESSION["UserName"]` is set to the users name.
2. At the top of each page, you check the session to see if the username session is valid and update the user table in the database to say he is actively browsing (using the timestamp field).
3. Check the user table and clear all logged in flags where the user has been inactive for X minutes.

Comment: I know that but across different computer the sessions vary and I need to check on another computer if the user is already logged in

Comment: Yes but how do I make this timer

Comment: cron is available only on UNIX and I am working currently on windows(it has to be platform independent at the end).

Comment: Ok, so run the code at the top of each page then (after the check to see if the Session is valid and timestamp updated).