# Block two login with the same user and password in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I created a db mysql, but I realized that if I open two sessions with the same user and password, from two different ips, the system does not tell me that the same user is logged in, i would like to know if and how Make that if a user has an open session, the second user with the same login data can not log in. It's possible to do it?

This is how to create a database

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `id` char(23) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(65) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(65) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(65) NOT NULL,
  `verified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `mod_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username_UNIQUE` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `loginAttempts` (
  `IP` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Attempts` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LastLogin` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Username` varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The contents of the loginheader file

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("location:login/main_login.php");
}
```

The contents of the Checklogin file

```
<?php
//DO NOT ECHO ANYTHING ON THIS PAGE OTHER THAN RESPONSE
//'true' triggers login success
ob_start();
include 'config.php';
require 'includes/functions.php';

// Define $myusername and $mypassword
$username = $_POST['myusername'];
$password = $_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);

$response = '';
$loginCtl = new LoginForm;
$conf = new GlobalConf;
$lastAttempt = checkAttempts($username);
$max_attempts = $conf->max_attempts;


//First Attempt
if ($lastAttempt['lastlogin'] == '') {

    $lastlogin = 'never';
    $loginCtl->insertAttempt($username);
    $response = $loginCtl->checkLogin($username, $password);

} elseif ($lastAttempt['attempts'] >= $max_attempts) {

    //Exceeded max attempts
    $loginCtl->updateAttempts($username);
    $response = $loginCtl->checkLogin($username, $password);

} else {

    $response = $loginCtl->checkLogin($username, $password);

};

if ($lastAttempt['attempts'] < $max_attempts && $response != 'true') {

    $loginCtl->updateAttempts($username);
    $resp = new RespObj($username, $response);
    $jsonResp = json_encode($resp);
    echo $jsonResp;

} else {

    $resp = new RespObj($username, $response);
    $jsonResp = json_encode($resp);
    echo $jsonResp;

}

unset($resp, $jsonResp);
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a user is logged in on another computer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727575/how-can-i-check-if-a-user-is-logged-in-on-another-computer)

Comment: Thanks for replying, you might have the same topic, I can create an "isLogged" column, my problem is how to make it work, I probably have to put a check, but how can I do it?

Comment: `stripslashes()` does **not** protect from SQL injection.